# Please merge my accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have another account here which, for some reason, I cannot login to: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/572/jim-armstrong

I tried to do an account recovery, but the openID it sends me isn't recognized and I'm essentially locked out of my account.

This is OK, since this account is linked to my other stackexchange sites, so I'd rather use this one...can a mod/admin merge my other account into this one so I can have all my questions/answers/etc under one account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be all set. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Looks good, thanks PJ!!